# Scroll a page (deostar.one) to bottom using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to load the table in https://daostar.one/Members-b338c6637de84b3ead9bd5dc8922c5b6

So far I tried

```
async function autoScroll(page){
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var distance = 100;
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;

                if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight - window.innerHeight){
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 70);
        });
    });
}
```

and

```
await page.waitForXPath('//div[@class="notion-table-view"]');
let elem = await page.$x('//div[@class="notion-table-view"]');
const boundingBox = await elem[0].boundingBox();

await page.mouse.move(
    boundingBox.x + boundingBox.width / 2,
    boundingBox.y + boundingBox.height / 2
);

await page.mouse.wheel({deltaY: -100});
```

which works fine on other pages but not this one.

Is there any other way to scroll the page or someway to get the full table data without scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty short table and you can get all of its elements after they load by waiting for table rows selector:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://daostar.one/Members-b338c6637de84b3ead9bd5dc8922c5b6');
  await page.waitForSelector('.notion-collection-item');
  const csv = await page.evaluate(() => [...document.querySelectorAll('.notion-collection-item')].map(div => div.innerText.replaceAll('\n', ';')))
  console.log(csv.join('\n'));
  await browser.close();
})();
```

However it may not work for longer tables, so you can indeed scroll the whole page by finding the element which is supposed to be scrolled, in this case not a `window` but this one:

```
const scroller = document.querySelector('.notion-scroller.vertical');
scroller.scrollBy(0, distance);
```

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no need to scroll in this case. This is a bit more verbose than [Vaviloff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75658151/6243352), but doesn't involve string manipulation, which can fail if the data items within elements happen to have commas, semicolons or newlines.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.waitForSelector(".notion-collection-item");
  const data = await page.$$eval(
    ".notion-collection-item",
    els =>
      els.map(e =>
        [...e.querySelectorAll(":scope > div")]
          .map(e =>
            [...e.querySelectorAll("*")]
              .filter(e =>
                [...e.childNodes].every(
                  e => e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
                )
              )
              .map(e => e.textContent.trim())
              .filter(Boolean)
          )
          .filter(e => e.length)
      )
  );
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.length);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

In plain language, the code grabs all top-level divs within a row (cells) and loops over them, drilling down to text nodes and turning them into a list. This preserves columns like names which may have multiple elements within it.

The website has a dearth of reasonable classes or identifiers, so I think this is about as good as it gets.

You may want to turn this 3d array into an array of objects:

```js
data = data.map(e => ({
  name: e[0][0],
  website: e[1][0],
  tags: e[2],
  people: e[3],
  date: e[4][0],
}));
```

`tags` looks to be a singleton, so you could use `e[2][0]` if this is the case.

By the way, the day appears to come in a single AJAX call, but the data is in a pretty cyptic deeply-nested JSON format that seems harder to manipulate than the DOM.

Comment: Yeah, I too wanted to use the raw data from internal API at first, sadly they store it that way 